# Content of select items is not set when reloading using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a code that is able to create a pair of selects and input elements with `ng-repeat` upon pressing a button. The elements are defined in a seperate directive:

```
<select ng-model="rule.parameter" ng-options="sel1.name for sel1 in selects1" ng-change="change(rule.parameter)"></select>
```

The data can be saved to a parameter `$scope.mydata` by pressing a button in the controller section:

```
<button ng-click="save(myselects)">Save data</button>
```

The js code is as follows:

```
$scope.save = function(filter) {
    $scope.mydata = JSON.stringify(filter, null, 2);    
};
```

Now suppose we have save our data from `$scope.mydata` in a file (see *mydata.txt* in [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9GUkIvOuSHU11jZx7GI?p=preview)). When the user presses another button to get the data back, the elements are supposed to be generated and displayed again:

```
<button ng-click="getData()">Get data</button>
```

Code in JavaScript to get the data back:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'mydata.txt'
    }).success(function(data) {
      if (data != null && data != "") {
        $scope.myselects = data;        
      }
    });
};
```

My problem is, that the elements in the select boxes are not set when I click that button. The content of the input field is set but that of the two select boxes is not.

Can anyone help me on this?

The complete Fiddle is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9GUkIvOuSHU11jZx7GI?p=preview). Just click on the *Get data* button (there is some content in *mydata.txt* already).

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value.

When you load the data from `mydata.txt` the model (`rule.parameter`) for the first select will be:

```
{"name":"Item1","relation":"default"}
```

The array of options will contain an item that looks the same, but it will still be another object.

For example, this will log `false`:

```
var object1 = {"name":"Item1","relation":"default"};
var object2 = {"name":"Item1","relation":"default"};

console.log(object1 === object2);
```

One solution is to use `track by` to instead identify the objects by a value of a property. Note that the value of the property you choose must be **unique**.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="rule.parameter" 
        ng-options="sel1.name for sel1 in selects1 track by sel1.name" 
        ng-change="change(rule.parameter)"></select>
```

To get the second select to work properly you need to build the filtered array not only when you change the selected value of the first select, but also upon initialization.

For example, add the following to the link function of dynamicSelectPair:

```
if (scope.rule.parameter) scope.change(scope.rule.parameter);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ANWhMcUh86MSeOi3WCV3?p=preview

Comment: One other question @tasseKATT: what do I have to do, when I have nested repeat-elements like this: [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KuqzYUQe9v4ghc8zknNo?p=preview). The relations of the nested group are not set when I click on the _get Data_ button (click on the button twice to load the data). Do I have to provide an $index or something?

Comment: Is this working as expecetd? http://plnkr.co/edit/TOoqnCkF5NScoaHPKl8B?p=preview I only had a few minutes to take a look at it. If it's not, I will take a further look when I have more time tonight.

Comment: Hi there, no unfortunately it's not. The data in each second select box of the indented four ng-repeat elements is not set. When I output the content of `{{filteredselect2}}`, the respective arrays are empty for the indented/nested select boxes. I have no idea why :(

Comment: The problem is that the `$scope.change` function in dynamicSelectPair will run before the $http call from dynamicSelect has finished, which means `scope.selects2` will be empty. One way to solve it is to prevent the directive from compiling before the data is available `<div dynamic-select-pair ng-if="selects1.length && selects2.length"` (http://plnkr.co/edit/qYWqNFYQA7KFJLbjya3S?p=preview). Another is to use `$watch` to call `$scope.change` when for example the length of selects2 changes (http://plnkr.co/edit/iu3OPKv5ILFGowTwEamI?p=preview)

Comment: I think I will take the version with the `$watch`. Thanks alot for your time - you saved me hours! :)